# Dispatching an action in react with redux

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

I don't know how can I easy resolve the problem. I have a form that user can fill and send stuff to my database. Form has his own state for it (here for example is just username). I don't know how to call setState (to give message to user about result) after dispatching redux action. 
Function postDataBegin is simple and shows spinner only. I think there is a problem, cause this function is synchronous (tell me if not). How can i fix it? What should i learn?

```
submitForm = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { username } = this.state;
  if (!question) {
    this.setState({ messageToUser: "Fill the form" });
  } else {
    // onSubmit is redux action from props
    this.props.onSubmit(username);
    //HOW TO CALL THIS FUNCTION AFTER FUNC ABOVE?
    this.setState({ messageToUser: "Send" });
  }
};

<Form type="submit" onSubmit={this.submitForm}/>

export const postUserQuestion = username => dispatch => {
  dispatch(postDataBegin());
  return post(postUsernameAPI, username)
    .then(res => dispatch(postUsernameAPISucceeded(res)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(postUsernameAPIFailure(error)));
};
```

Comment: Hi, you must learn reducer.
After dispatch reducer called, then reducer update or set new state, and you can use this state with store.

Comment: Ye i know about it but i don't want to use reducer store only for simple message - my form is stateful component already. There is no other way? The problem is that my message in Form component shows immediately after I click on submit button - i want make it to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action returns a promise, so you can use `then` method on it to provide a callback:

```
submitForm = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { username } = this.state;
  if (!question) {
    this.setState({ messageToUser: "Fill the form" });
  } else {
    // onSubmit is redux action from props
    this.props.onSubmit(username).then(() => {
      this.setState({ messageToUser: "Send" });
    });
  }
};
```

Altho it'd probably be better to store that data on reducer as well, and change it the same time when the form is submitted.

Comment: Great! I knew it is all about the Promise. Thank you.